# I tried to add a CTA to a WordPress site. I placed on the header and I added this HTML code to the header.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web

Here;s the full header.php

http://collabedit.com/3au85

Here's the code that I added:

```
 <!-- This is my extra div element-->   
<div class="extra-top"><a class="extra-topie" href="tel:6172010333">Call Us Now: (617) 201-0333</a></div>
 <!-- Ends extra div element-->
```

But the Anchor text is not working: it's not clickable yet. I mean its static and does nothing and it should show the tel: hyperlink .

Please share your thoughts!

Cheers

Comment: `tel:` href's require a `+` trunk prefix for the number. ie. `tel:+6172010333`. Also for readability, potentially use hyphens. (PS. that doesnt look like a valid australian number)

Comment: So I should move the extra DIV somewhere else, I see I;ll try that thanks mate

Comment: Thanks bro, I added the + to the phone # but the hyperlink tel is not clickable yet :(

Comment: [Since 1995-07-17 you'll need to add the additional `3` before your 7 digit phone number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Former_Australian_dialling_codes), So your number should end up looking like `tel:+61-7-3201-0333` i believe. Also https://jsfiddle.net/ayhaths6/1/ appears to be clickable here. Have you got a `z-index`ing issue where the link is being covered?

Comment: I see , Thanks bro. I'll do that but the tel: still does not work :(. perhaps i should move it somewhere else. I mean in the header.php file

Comment: I am starting to think this is a layering issue. You can test this by putting the link somewhere else and seeing if it's clickable (it almost certainly will be). At this point, put it back to where you want it, and look at how you can raise its `z-index` using css to have it sit ABOVE other layers.

Comment: Yes, Sir you nailed it! that was the issue.Thanks! now i'll have to play with the z-index values

Comment: Sir, I would buy you a beer. You really saved my day! Thanks mate!

Comment: This is the DIVI theme. Are you aware that there is an option "secondary menu" in the Divi theme options which lets you insert a phone number above the regular menu in the header, without having to write any code?

Comment: @DaveBud, well im only down the road :P Woolloongabba has some nice bars hahah :)

Comment: Thanks Mate! I'll hit you up next time I'm in town haha :)